# Drawing a round shadow on a square element with CSS

Tags: css, shadow

Is it possible creating a *round* shadow (a neat circle with the spread value set to zero) under a square element?
E.g. a DIV with no rounded borders.

I have the following element, which I cannot add further markup to:

```
<div class="square"></div>
```

In addition, I cannot use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, as they are already styled. That's why I am trying to adapt the box-shadow.

In the example below what I would like to achieve (obtained with a ":before" pseudo-element, which I cannot use).

```css
.circle {
  width: 20px;height: 20px; margin: 40px 0 0 40px;
  display: inline-block; border:1px solid #000;
  position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; background: #fff;
}
.circle:before {
  content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; top: -15px; left: -15px;
  width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%; background: #ddd;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

I used the `:before` pseudo-element only to show the result.

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing this...would it look like a square/rectangle encased in a circle? What about having two divs, one outer with transparent background?

Comment: can you share an image of what you need ? it's a bit confusing

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a quite good solution:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-left: 5rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.element {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #5f5f5f;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.element:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.2;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

I hope it will be a helpful answer for you, - Marta.

Comment: Nice job Marta and +1, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately my project constraints did not allow to add any markup, so the underlying question was: can a CSS shadow be circular on a square element? And unfortunately the answer is no, as investigated with Jesse Phillips.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to go about it.  I'd simply put the square div in a bigger container div, then style it as you wish.  I've included a couple of examples for you.

I hope this helps! - James.

```css
.square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.circle,.circle-with-spread {
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle-with-spread {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<!-- Example Circle Shadow -->
<div class="circle">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
<!-- Spacing makes it look nice -->
<br />
<br />
<br />
<!-- Second Example -->
<div class="circle-with-spread">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear James, thanks for your response. Sorry, I think I have not been clear enough: I neither can add further markup beyond the DIV to style, nor can use pseudo-elements. The only space I have is crafting the shadow through its CSS properties; I investigated the box-shadow properties but I did not achieve a solution, so I wanted to se if I was missing something, if there was a rabbit to pull out of the cylinder...

Comment: I edited the question to better explain the problem.

Comment: I understand now.  As far as I can see, there isn't a way of achieving what you want without using pseudo-elements, markup, or JavaScript.  There are a couple of *close* alternatives, but they're not perfect.  Adding `box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 #000;` gives you the circular shadow, but it has spread, or adding `box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #000;` gives you the shadow without spread, but it's square. - Sorry I couldn't help you any further.

Comment: Ok, at least I am a bit more convinced not to have neglected something... Thanks